# DC motor torque control with a transistor

Tags: motor, torque

I need a transistor circuit to shut off a small dc motor when its torque under load reaches a predetermined level using the current drawn by the motor under load?

Comment: Yes, current is proportional to torque. Sense the current, compare to your max current reference, and turn the motor off if it exceeds the maximum desired torque.  This is a Q & A site, so we really don't provide designs.  The implementation is up to you.  If you show and attempt (schematic) we can provide feedback though.

Comment: Be aware that you'll need some type of 'memory' function (a latch) as when you do turn off the motor, the current will revert to 0, and without a memory, the circuit will likely turn on the motor again -- either oscillating or regulating the current at the detection level (and possibly causing overheating in the driver circuit).